# An inequality with integrals on $K=[a,b]\times[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be limited on $[a, b]$. Suppose $\int_a^bf(x)\mbox{d}x$ exists. Taking under condideration an integral $$\int_K[f(x)-f(y)^2]\mbox{d}(x,y)$$ where $K = [a,b]\times[a,b]$ prove the following inequality
$$\bigg(\int_a^bf(x)\mbox{d}x\bigg)^2 \le (b-a)\int_a^bf^2(x)\mbox{d}x$$

Comment: Apply Cauchy -Schwartz inequality (or Holder's inequality) writing f as product of 1 and f.

Comment: Just expand the square term and integrate in each variable separately using Fubini’s Theorem. Alternatively, this is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $L^2$ applied to the product $f\cdot 1$.